# CURL error with REST API

Tags: apache, curl

Having a very odd behavior. Using site health plugin; I was getting errors with CURL & Loopback. At any rate, I fixed both these issues on the server; however, it appears that other websites (also wordpress) on the same server still exhibit the error. Is there someway to make WP notice the changes that I am missing?

Comment: How did you fix the original problem?

Comment: Updated PHP & made sure /etc/hosts file was accurate (which it wasn't). These are general things; which is why I figured it would affect all three sites on the box. However, it only seems to have fixed the issue with 1 site. Maybe it is the hosts names to website name for the loopback; but the CURL I absolutely do not understand. 

Oh, and I added 
CACERT: PATHTOFILE

in the system wide php.ini